# Unix Shell command to copy all files inside current directory to subdirectory

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, terminal

I want to copy all files inside my current directory to a new subdirectory. What is the unix command for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy all '*files*' you will need to exclude the copy of other subdirectories. You can do that with a short loop and compound-command, e.g.

```
for i in *; do [ -f "$i" ] && cp -a "$i" directoryname; done
```

There are several ways to do it. Let me know if that gives you any trouble.

And since you are new to shell programming, a *compound-command* is simply two commands (or more) tied together with `&&` (which means execute the second if the first succeeds) and `||` (which means execute the second only if the first fails). So above, the loop simply does the following:

```
for i in *; do                                 # for each linux-file in dir
    [ -f "$i" ] && cp -a "$i" directoryname    # test if plain file && copy
done
```

Comment: Great. works well. directory should be exists to run the command.

Comment: You can always add path information to prevent having to change into a directory first. But, get comfortable with handling files within a directory and then we will work on handling files at remote-path locations within the filesystem. Glad it worked for you `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cp -R` command. With `-R` flag it **copies directories recursively.**

For example:

```
cp -R directory1/ directory2/
```

copies whole `directory1` to `directory2`.

Comment: well. I want to copy files inside current directory. `cp -R * directory2/` doesn't work.

Comment: So you need to use a **dot** instead of an **asterisk**, like this: `cp -R . directory2/`

Comment: Doesn't work mate. This will end up in recursively copy the directory2 inside itself including new content. Goes to kind of infinite loop. Which shell will kill once detected infinity.

Answer (score -1):

Replace the sub-directory-name:

$cp -R * sub-directory-name/

Comment: sorry, it not works. Your shell command will create much much directory sub-directory-name  in  sub-directory-name.